# c# event can enter to function twice in same time?

Tags: c#, events, port

```
SerialPort s = new SerialPort("COM32");
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    s.DataReceived += dataAction;
}
private void dataAction(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

the function `dataAction` can be run on same time with 2 event?

or `dataAction` apply only when the last event finish?

I must to know that to know If i need to put lock on this function

Answer (score 0):

Event will trigger everytime they are called. If they are called multiple times from multiple threads they will be triggered synchronously.

However, in your specific case, it seems you register to a specific element which seems to be monothreaded (can't be sure as I don't know SerialPort api)